# Xcode 9.3 crashes in SourceEditorDataSource.insertTextAtPosition

Tags: xcode, crash

I've had Xcode just exit when I tried to edit certain files in the project. It was always crashing in SourceEditorDataSource.insertTextAtPosition, with this line in the report:

specialized closure #3 in SourceEditorDataSource.insertTextAtPosition(_:position:reformatting:) + 1905

I was puzzled because it was only certain files that were causing the problem. Other files in the same project were ok. For some reason I looked at the file in BBEdit and found that it was using carriage returns. When I used BBEdit to set the file to use line feeds, the crash went away.

I used grep to find all the files with '\r' and verified that each of them would cause Xcode to exit. I edited all the files, and no more crashing.

I filed a bug and Apple has marked it as duplicate, so they know of the problem. And now you do too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just marking the question as answered, since there is a workaround and Apple is aware of the bug in Xcode.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable, I think; in 48 hours you can accept your own answer and complete the cycle. — Personally I wish I had a nickel for every time Xcode 9.3 has simply vanished off the screen, or frozen, or refused to quit, or eaten up all the CPU. It's atrocious.

Comment: i disabled source control - seemed to fix it. only noticed blue bar and Discard Change appear randomly. may also cause Xcode 10 and 9 to crash. as I think XCode 10 turns source control on if it was off in XCode 9